# Error: The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect to a folder exactly as the subdomain. Subdomain should be dynamic. For that I use the htaccess code given below. But getting error message `The page isn't redirecting properly` in firefox.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Options +Indexes
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com.au$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why the PHP tag? Also, could you add the URL you enter and what you expect the result to become? A tips is also to enable [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) to troubleshoot redirect rules.

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly add php tag. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an additional check that the directory isn't *already* in the subdomain's directory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com.au$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %2::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com.au$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. But it didn't worked.
The directory is in subdomain's directory itself.

Comment: I have replaced last line with this 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2/$1 [NC,L]
and that worked.

Comment: Thanks again. Last three days I was struggling with this.

Comment: @user2955900 no problem, sorry about the typo